# How to console.log all inherited properties?

Tags: javascript, object, inheritance

Sorry for noob question. I'm just learning JavaScript.

I have an easy Object.

```
var bike = {
  wheels: 2,
};
```

I create a new one that inherits all the bike values via create() and add some new properties to new Object.

```
var raleigh = Object.create(bike);
raleigh.color = 'red';
```

When I do console.log on new raleigh Object I can't see propeties inherited from bike Object.

```
console.log(raleigh);
```

The log is:

```
{ color: 'red' }
```

How to log to console all properties including these inherited?

Comment: You need to follow `prototype` chain in `console`

Comment: see this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create

Comment: In chrome you can expand the faded `__proto__`

Answer (score 4):

When an object is printed through `console.log`, it is printed with all its own properties and a link to the object it inherits from. You can see all the inherited properties in console, you just need to follow the prototype chain of the displayed object (typically using `__proto__` or `[[prototype]]` keys).

Comment: You should see `__proto__` as one of the object's properties in the console - click on that to expand it.

Comment: @MattBrowne I think it is browser dependent

Comment: @Bergi Thank you for making answer more informative

Answer (score 3):

When you use `Object.create` then your prototype will be the same the object that you are inheriting, so, to show "father" properties you could see the prototype:

```
console.log(raleigh);
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(raleigh));
```

Maybe you will expect something more but I think that is the fast way to show that properties.

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you. Later on i fount this, that does the same job.

console.log(raleigh.__proto__);

Comment: You are welcome @PawełGrzybek ;) Previously I wrote raleigh.__proto__ but a moderator updated my answer maybe because is not compatible with all browsers.

Comment: And probably he was right https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto Thanks guys! Im a new user of Stack Overflow, but I already love it!

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new *Object* especially for your log which has everything as *own properties*

```
function flatten_inheritance(e) {
    var o = Object.create(null), i, prop;
    do {
        prop = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(e);
        for (i = 0; i < prop.length; ++i)
            if (!(prop[i] in o))
                o[prop[i]] = e[prop[i]];
    } while (e = Object.getPrototypeOf(e));
    return o;
}

flatten_inheritance(raleigh); // Object {color: "red", wheels: 2, valueOf, toString, etc..}
```

If you want to stop at `Object.prototype` or some other prototype you can do this in the `while` condition for example;

```
while (e = Object.getPrototypeOf(e) && e !== Object.prototype);
```

I would recommend you only do this when debugging rather than moving all your code away from inheritance though

Comment: What happened to the `Object.prototype` methods, shouldn't they be displayed as well?

Comment: @Bergi this method does include them, let me make it more obvious

Answer (score 0):

Would this help?
I'm throwing an alert, u can check the console as well!

```js
 var bike = {
      wheels: 2,
    };
    var raleigh = Object.create(bike);
    raleigh.color = 'red';
    function getAllProperties( obj ) {
        var properties = [];
    
        do {
            properties= properties.concat(Object.getOwnPropertyNames( obj ));
        } while ( obj = Object.getPrototypeOf( obj ) );
    
        return properties;
    }
    alert(getAllProperties(raleigh));
    console.log(getAllProperties(raleigh));
```