# how object contains function save

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

why save function works with (user) even though user does not have this function
and when I print user it doesn't have any save function
I did not use findByIdAndUpdate because I wanna use pre before save or update user
I searched on google but didn't find a solution

index.js

```
const User = require('../models/user')
  user = await User.findById(req.params.id)
  user['password']='xxxxx'
   await user.save()
```

User File

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const validator = require('validator')
const bcrypt=require('bcryptjs')
const userSchema=mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true,
        lowercase: true,
        validate(value) {
            if (!validator.isEmail(value)) {
                throw new Error('Email is invalid')
            }
        }
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        minlength: 7,
        trim: true,
        validate(value) {
            if (value.toLowerCase().includes('password')) {
                throw new Error('Password cannot contain "password"')
            }
        }
    },
    age: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0,
        validate(value) {
            if (value < 0) {
                throw new Error('Age must be a postive number')
            }
        }
    }
})
 userSchema.pre('save', async function (next) {
    const user = this

    if (user.isModified('password')) {
        user.password = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, 8)
    }

    next()
}) 
const User = mongoose.model('User',userSchema )


module.exports = User
```

console.log(user) output

```
  {
  age: 20,
  _id: 5f738c48bbf1cc3b2647a35b,
  name: 'momo',
  email: 'momomo@gmail.com',
  password: 'sj,sksaklas,ans',
  __v: 0
}
```

console.log(user['save']) output

```
[Function (anonymous)]
```

Answer (score 0):

The `User` value is returned by the function call `mongoose.model('User',userSchema )`

The `save()` function is defined here: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/master/lib/model.js#L424-L505

When you pass an object to `console.log` it typically displays only the objects [own](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) properties, not inherited ones.  i.e. `save` is not displayed when logging a mongoose model for the same reason that console.log doesnn't display `match`, `indexOf`, `ltrim`, `replace`, etc. when logging a string.

If you really want to see the inherited properties, this might be a starting point for you:
[How to console.log all inherited properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31100403/how-to-console-log-all-inherited-properties)